# How can we create a PDF based on SQL data?

Tags: sql, mysql, html, pdf, vbscript

i just wondered if any users could advise me what to google for, as im wanting to create a pdf after a user has submitted a vbscript form.

The form contains data which goes into a MYSQL database and once the user has submitted i would like to use the data to create a PDF.

I would probably be calling this from the vbscript, so i wondered how can i create the PDF from vbscript? Would i have to make an external call to some other program/website or something? Do we need Adobe Acrobat Professional and could it be installed on our server to allow us to systematically create PDFs on the fly?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a PDF com component.

There are many of these around - anything that works with classic ASP will work.

This is one I used int the past - [AspPDF](http://www.asppdf.com/).

Answer (score 0):

we also use PDFCreator which is installed on the server and works like a printer.  The output is a PDF.